# Unable to access apache2 server from any machine except localhost

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, apache2, local-area-network

I have a Magento2 instance set up on a server running Ubuntu 20.04.

When I open a browser from that machine I can access the webpage using any of: `magento.local`, `127.0.0.1`, and `192.168.20.11` (which I got from `ip addr`).

As soon as I access `192.168.20.11` from any other machine, the request times out.

I tried allowing port 80 on the firewall using `ufw` which seemed to work correctly but I still could not access the page from another machine. I then disabled the firewall completely and it's still not working from any other machine on the network.

It seems to me that apache is only listening on localhost and not on the local network, or that my ubuntu machine is not discoverable on the network - though I have not found anything that would indicate this is the case.

Running `nmap -Pn 192.168.20.11` from the another machine shows that the host is up but that all 1000 scanned ports are filtered.

I've done a quick sanity check to make sure all the machines are on the same network, and no problems there.

It seems I also cannot connect to the machine via ssh.
I changed my `ports.conf` to have `Listen 0.0.0.0:80` and now netstat is showing listening for both `0.0.0.0:ssh` as well as `0.0.0.0:http`, and now instead of timing out I get "Host is down".

Comment: A filrewall? What is `iptables-save` output?

Comment: When you say you disabled the firewall... Did you stop the service for UFW or did you do ufw disable? If you stop the service, you break everything however if you disable UFW by the above command then that's fine.

Comment: You can be fairly sure, Apache listens on both. But from local machine you always access your own computer using loopback interface. That shows you are facing connection issue or network (firewall) configuration issue. Can you ping your server from other computers? Can you access any other TCP service on that computer? Can you disable or enable access to that service using the tools of your choice (or are you willing to switch to generic low-level tools such as iptables)?

Comment: To check the listening ports, try `netstat` (from package `net-tools`): `sudo netstat -lnp | grep :80`. If you could post here, what it is saying, the community could help better.

Comment: Hi all, I think this may be a problem at the router level as I was able to access the host via ssh and accessing the web server gave a 301 response, when I connected both machines to a mobile hotspot instead of my home network. I didn’t have time to investigate further but I will come back with more info after work today.